# $H$ is admissible, then $P\rightarrow P/H$ is a principle $H$ -bundle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

> [Proposition 3.5, page 5:](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Embehren1/18.906/prin.pdf) Suppose $P \rightarrow B$ is a principal $G$-bundle, and let $H$ be an admissible subgroup of $G$. Then the quotient map $P \rightarrow P/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle.
>
> **Definition:**    Call a subgroup $H$ of $G$ admissible if the quotient map $G \rightarrow G/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle.

The proof given goes as follows: we can identify the map with the map,
$$P \times_G G \rightarrow P \times_G (G/H)$$
and we utilize the fact that $H$ of $G$ is admissible.

---

Now I could not really spell out the maps of local trivilization, we want open set of $P \times_G (G/H)$ such that its preimage, in $P \times_G G$ has a local trivilization.

---

**Justifying this seems like a mess. I would like to see some neat approach.**

---

My attempt goes as follows.

Since the quotient map is an open map, take a local trivilization, open set $U$ of $G/H$, so $P \times U$ has open image in $P \times_G(G/H)$, where $\pi:G \rightarrow G/H$, under quotient $t:P \times G/H \rightarrow P \times_G (G/H)$

Consider its preimage, which I believe should be the image of $P \times \pi^{-1}(U)$ under the quotient. $s:P \times G \rightarrow P \times_G G$

So we show that we have a $G$-homeomorphism,

$$ s(P \times \pi^{-1}(U)) \rightarrow t(P \times U) \times (P \times_G G/H)$$

Everything here seems messy. But is this right?

Comment: what is your $P\times_GG$ and $P\times_{G/H}G/H$??

Comment: A principal bundle is trivial if and only if it has a section. Take a trivialisation of $p:P\rightarrow B$ over an open subset $V\subseteq B$ and consider the image of $p^{-1}(V)\times U$ in $P\times_GG/H$, where $U$ here is the same as you consider above.

Comment: Thanks Tyrone, I will try spell this out, @Koushik, those are defined as in the notes, we quotient out by the diagonal action when $P \times G$ is regarded as a $G$ space, i.e. $(pg,h) \sim (p,gh)$.  for $p \in P, g,h \in G$.