# Universal principal bundle of a subgroup $H \subseteq G$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, principal-bundles

This was claimed in the referenced link:

> If $H \subseteq G$ is an admissible subgroup, i.e. $G \rightarrow G/H$ is a principal $H$ bundle.
>
> Let $EG  \rightarrow BG$ be a model universal principal bundle of $G$ (if exists).
>
> Then $EG \times_H G\rightarrow EG/H$ is a universal principal bundle for $H$.  i.e. $EG/H$ is classifying space for $H$.

This does not seem clear to me. How does the last line follow?

EDIT: It seems to me that it suffices to show

1. $EG \times_H G$ is a principal $H$-bundle.
2. It is weakly contractible, so we can apply theorem 7.4.

Reference: [Page 17, paragraph before prop 8.3, notes by Stephen Mitchell](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Embehren1/18.906/prin.pdf)

Comment: This is not what Prop 8.3 says.

Comment: This is before Prop 8.3, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $EG$ is a free contractible $G$-space, it is a a free contractible $H$-space for any subgroup $H\leq G$. Hence the projection

$$p_H:EG\rightarrow EG/H$$

onto $H$-orbits will satisfy the properties for it to be the universal $H$-principal bundle as long as the local-triviality condition is met. This is Propositions 7.4, 7.5.

To see that it is indeed locally trivial we appeal to the single assumption. We use the bundle-isomorphisms

$$EG\cong EG\times_G G$$

and

$$EG/H\cong(EG\times_GG)/H\cong EG\times_G(G/H)$$

to see that $p_H$ is exactly the map

$$p_H:EG\times_GG\rightarrow EG\times_G(G/H).$$

Then local triviality follows from the work we did on a previous question you asked, since it is just the associated bundle to an admissible group quotient.

Edit: also see proposition 3.5.

Comment: Hello is that possible for you to link the post regarding " the associated bundle to an admissible group quotient"? Thanks!

Comment: @6666 I might have been referring to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080725/h-is-admissible-then-p-rightarrow-p-h-is-a-principle-h-bundle). You can look through Brian's other questions from this time period and maybe find something more specific.

Comment: thank you very much!